Как создать 4К эмулятор в Android Studio?
Мне нужно создать эмулятор 4K в Android Studio, как на скриншоте ниже:

Согласно конфигурации, разрешение должно быть 3840x2160, а density xxxhdpi, что соответствует 640. У меня есть приложение, в котором я пытаюсь получить разрешение и density и отобразить их на экране.

Код:
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
            ) {
                val screenDensity: Float = LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi.toFloat()

                Text(
                    color = ColorTokens.white,
                    text = "screenDensity: $screenDensity"
                )

                Text(
                    color = ColorTokens.white,
                    text = "height: ${LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels}"
                )

                Text(
                    color = ColorTokens.white,
                    text = "width: ${LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels}"
                )
            }

Вопрос - что я упускаю здесь - почему 4K эмулятор имеет совершенно другую конфигурацию?
UPD
Эмулятор на версии UpsideDownCake API 34:

